# Ipad "Not charging" with Ubuntu 16.04 and ipad_charge could not work

Tags: ubuntu, ipad, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and want to charge my ipad under the Ubuntu system.

**Description**

The computer runs on Ubuntu 16.04. When plugin into the computer, the ipad shows a "Not charging" icon near the battery icon.

I have tried for installing ipad_charge. However, I meet the error

Unable to claim the interface: error (-6).

**Question**

Many articles says this is related to the power of the USB. Yet no other method is mentioned other than this ipad_charge. So I'm wondering if there is any method to charge the ipad or any hint on how I could fix this "unable to claim the interface" problem with ipad_charge.

Thanks a lot.

**Solution**

This is solved. Please refer to Alex_Krug's solution in the reply. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Stackoverflow is about coding, don't know if you are at the correct place to ask this question.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right. I have posted a request to Apple Support. I just want to see if someone knows this ipad_charge by chance and could figure me out how to fix this "Unable to claim the interface: error (-6)"

Comment: Good luck with your search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works on the 14.04. For 16.04 the patch is created http://02.lv/f/2017/01/21/ipad_charge

Source - https://github.com/mkorenkov/ipad_charge/issues/42